# How to get list (full path) of files exist in folder and subfolder in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, directory, subdirectory, filelist

I would like to get the list of files exist in folder and subfolder with full path.Don’t want any blank folder or subfolder path in list.

Example.
(File exist on path)
~\Folder1
\Subfolder1
\File1.jpg

(No file on this path, blank folder)
~\Folder2
\Subfolder2\

(File exist on path)
~\Folder3
\Subfolder3
\File3.png

*Result
.\Folder1\Subfolder1\File1.jpg
.\Folder3\Subfolder3\File3.png

I tried dir /s /b>list.txt command in cmd but also getting path on blank folder path that I don’t want.

Answer (score 1):

Simply ask `dir` to remove directories... Being a directory is considered as an attribute.

`dir /s /b /a:-D > list.txt`